# How do I change the capitalization formatting of my Taxonomy terms programatically?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I am using taxonomy terms with the formatting where the first Letter of the phrase (if there is more than one word in the taxonomy) is capitalized, and then the others are not. So, for examples 'Cars and trucks'

In house we have made the decision to change these so that every major word is capitalized, so, 'Cars and Trucks,' excluding minor words like and, it, but, etc - basically the word list that is in the Path auto terms to exclude.

I have thousands of terms. More over, there was a point when the community contributed them so there is no consistency.

Thoughts on how to tackle this without having to edit them one by one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly easy to cobble some (admittedly inefficient) code together that will convert a string to title case while ignoring certain words (you'll have to choose the words yourself though):

```
function _MYMODULE_custom_title_case($string, $blacklist = array()) {
  // Split the words into an array
  $words = explode(' ', $string);

  $new_words = array();
  foreach ($words as $word) {
    // If the word isn't in the blacklist, capitalise it.
    if (!in_array($word, $blacklist)) {
      $word = ucfirst($word);
    }

    $new_words[] = $word;
  }

  // Join the string back up and return it.
  return implode(' ', $new_words);
}
```

Then you can simply load all of the terms in your vocabulary, change the title, and save them:

```
$vid = 1; // Vocabulary ID
$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid); // Get the terms

// User the pathauto blacklist
$blacklist = variable_get('pathauto_ignore_words', array()); 
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  // Update
  $term->name = _MYMODULE_custom_title_case($term->name, $blacklist);

  // And save
  taxonomy_term_save($term);
}
```

I confess to not having tested that so use a bit of caution! If you've got a lot of terms you might want to split it up into batches to avoid hitting a PHP timeout.

Answer (score 0):

The term that you are looking for is [title case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Headings_and_publication_titles). I should note that you're going to have to deal with edge cases such as abbreviations etc. For example, USA, U.A.E, usa will very likely all be handled incorrectly. I recommend that you adapt [this](http://individed.com/code/to-title-case/) JavaScript for your needs as it works reasonably well.

I believe that you can *add* revision support to taxonomy term fields. If this is reasonably straightforward to achieve, it might be worth considering to ensure that your script is not destructive. Moreover, revisions will make the handling of the aforementioned edge cases a lot easier.

I'm unsure if the [Unitag](http://drupal.org/project/unitag) module handles such functions for user *input*. But it might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

If it is for display only, thus not in your database, use this CSS property:

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```

Works in all browsers.